# Python's Sequence Matcher gives incomplete match

Tags: python, sequence, matching

I am trying to find matching blocks between two strings using Python's `SequenceMatcher`. The strings are `"ABCDPQRUVWXYZ"` and `"PQRABCDUVWXYZ"`. However when I apply `get_matching_blocks()`, the string `"PQR"` is not found as a matching block.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

str1 = "ABCDPQRUVWXYZ"
str2 = "PQRABCDUVWXYZ"

matchAll = SequenceMatcher(None, str1, str2, False).get_matching_blocks()

for i in range(0, len(matchAll)):
    print(str1[matchAll[i].a: matchAll[i].a + matchAll[i].size])
```

Comment: Why were you expecting `PQR` to be found? It sounds like the task you want to perform isn't the task `difflib.SequenceMatcher` was written for.

Comment: is using `difflib.SequenceMatcher` a requirement for marking an answer as correct? are you bound to use this library?

Comment: docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks

Comment: Not really. My task is to find all matching blocks (all matching substrings) between two strings. I used Python's Sequence Matcher's get_matching_blocks() method. According to the documentation, this is supposed to find all the blocks, and it is indeed finding "ABCD" and "UVWXYZ" but not "PQR".

Comment: In the documentation, it says that "Each triple is of the form (i, j, n), and means that a[i:i+n] == b[j:j+n]. The triples are monotonically increasing in i and j".

Comment: You work with wrong module, check @Rickkwa comment ! Can't success if haven't any pattern, like `["A","ABCD","PQR","UVWXYZ","AB","CD"]` sort via by `length` before compare two list(`LONG FIRST`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do what you want - won't find overlapping matches though (revised to include string locations in s1 and s2 of the substrings):

```
str1 = "ABCDEPQRUVWXYZ" # added extra non-matching character
str2 = "PQRABCDUVWXYZ"

def find_subs(s1, s2):
    subs = []
    loc = 0
    while s1:
        s1_copy = s1
        while s1_copy:
            while s1_copy and s1_copy not in s2:
                s1_copy = s1_copy[:-1]
            if s1_copy:
                subs.append((loc, s2.index(s1_copy), s1_copy))
                loc += len(s1_copy)
                s1 = s1[len(s1_copy):]
            else:
                s1 = s1[1:]
                loc += 1
            s1_copy = s1                
    return subs

print(find_subs(str1, str2))
```

prints:

```
[(0, 3, 'ABCD'), (5, 0, 'PQR'), (8, 7, 'UVWXYZ')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks) state that:

> **get_matching_blocks()**
>
> Return list of triples describing matching subsequences. Each triple is of the form (i, j, n), and means that a[i:i+n] == b[j:j+n].
>   The triples are monotonically increasing in i and j.

If the function returned `"PQR"` in your example, the `j` wouldn't be monotonically increasing, as it would go from the `"A"` index for the `"ABCD"` match, back to the `"P"` index for the `"PQR"` match.

Comment: Sorry, in continuation of my previous comment, try: s1 = "ABCPQRSTUVWX" and s2 = "PQRSTABCUVWX". Now "ABC" is the common substring not found, so I don't think the issue with get_matching_blocks() is related to monotonic increase or decrease of "i" and "j". Infact, I think the monotonic increase is related to the indices within the common substring, not outside it.

Comment: Right, because pqrst is found first,  so the index i would be non-monotonic if it went back to abc in s1

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all coders who answered my post.

As a solution, I experimented and found another solution using

```
SequenceMatcher's find_longest_match()
```

method.  This consists of basically finding the longest match between two strings repeatedly and then by replacing the matched longest string each time with garbage characters. This works well too.